# Spring Javamail properties from Database

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to write a Spring(I use 3.0)  Application and use the Spring included Javamail.
I would like the javamail properties (stmp server, port, username, pass,etc) to be stored in a database for easy updating/changing. I've seen examples where Javamail properties are setup inside the `applicationContext.xml or in a properties` file.

but `is there a way to use a database to store the email properties and retrieve them every time I need to send a e-mail?`

my ApplicationContex.xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="465" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
    <property name="username" value="test@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="***********" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can.

1) First way

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"/>
```

In controller

```
@Autowired 
JavaMailSender mailSender


@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    // connect to database
    // obtain properties
    JavaMailSenderImpl ms = (JavaMailSenderImpl) mailSender;
    ms.set...
    ms.set...
    ms.set...
}
```

2) Second way

```
public class DatabaseBasedMailSender extends JavaMailSenderImpl{

    public DatabaseBasedMailSender(){
        // connect to database
        // obtain properties

        setHost(...)
        setProtocol(...)
        ...

    }


}

<bean id="mailSender" class="my.project.DatabaseBasedMailSender"/>
```

I am sure it is possible find another ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a properties file and from there you can get all the values like host,username,password ,I do'nt think that it is good idea to store in database,but if you want you can use..Any time you want to change in your mail setting ,you can go in properties 
file and change there,I have created separate util package for sending mail

```
public void sendMailWithAttachments(String to, String subject,
        String content, String[] attachFiles) {

    try {
        final String userName = com.sheel.property.Properties.userName;
        final String password = com.sheel.property.Properties.password;
        String from = com.sheel.property.Properties.mailFrom;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host",
                com.sheel.property.Properties.SMTP_HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",
                com.sheel.property.Properties.SMTP_PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port",
                com.sheel.property.Properties.SMTP_PORT);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication 

                    getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new    PasswordAuthentication(userName,
                                password);
                    }
                });

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try {
                    attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    throw ex;
                }

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }

        msg.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(msg);

        System.out.println("Mail sent");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And this is properties file

```
public interface Properties {
String SMTP_HOST = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
String SMTP_PORT = "465";
String incoming_server_host = "pop.secureserver.net";
String incoming_server_port = "995";
String userName = "test@gmail.com";
String password = "password";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Envious the reason why we go for database is the frequency of changing password is often done and if i have to go with properties file or ApplicationContex than I have to restart my server everytime when i change these details.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to create a singleton bean to initialize all your email related properties :

1. Obtain all the email related properties from DB and set them as
   System/Environment Property
2. Fetch all of those properties as required below with `System.getProperty("propertyName")`

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class EmailConfig {

   @Bean
   public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {

       JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
       mailSender.setHost("");
       mailSender.setPort(Integer.valueOf("");
       mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("");
       mailSender.setUsername("");
       mailSender.setPassword("");

       Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
       props.put("spring.mail.protocol","");
       props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable","");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth","");

       return mailSender;
      }
   }
   ```